# Undo a roll-back

Tags: discussion, edits

I there any way to undo an edit roll back made by another user? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088835/need-to-know-how-the-second-loop-works) post author undid a valid edit, and now the post is meaningless.

Comment: Another user with 2k rep could come along and roll-back -- but is it a question worth the effort? There'd be nothing to stop the OP continuing to revert edits.

Comment: Rollback and comment, then if the user continue to rollback, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

If a user is vandalizing their own post by rolling back appropriate edits then flag the post for moderator attention; they have the tools to deal with such a problem; if you keep trying to edit the post you'll just be starting a rollback war, which isn't productive.